# contentclass query does not return anything on https site, only return items on http

Tags: 2019, sharepoint-server

The user that execute this query it's de site administrator on the two sites.
HTTPS:
[image]

HTTP:
[image]

Comment: this is a bit spare of detail, you might want to give a bit more explanation to encourage some answers.  Welcome to the Sharepoint SE site though!

Comment: thanks @Tally, what others details could be interesting, some idea?